# node.js send data in async from function to function

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I'm going to create a node repl that works within a node.

The run function is a function that returns the output value when the code to be put in the repl is passed over to the factor.

Is there a way to transfer data from a write function to a run function while the run function is running?

```js
const repl = require('repl');
const { Readable, Writable } = require('stream');

const readable = new Readable({
    read(size) {
        return true;
    }
});
const writable = new Writable({
    write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        const value = chunk.toString();
        if (value === "") {
            // todo : send data to function run
        } else {
            // todo : stack data for function run
        }
        console.log(chunk);
        callback();
    }
});

repl.start({
    prompt: "",
    input: readable,
    output: writable
});

async function run(code) {
    readable.push(code);
    // todo 
}

run("setTimeout(() => {console.log('test')}, 1000);\n");

exports.run = run;
```

Comment: The wrong terminology makes this question unclear. No, you can't send data from one function to another function. You can store data in a common scope or service to access it. You can use messenger or observer pattern and register handlers.

Comment: thanks! I was wondering if there was a function like channel in golang.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.